# Why do I get 2 sets of children when i use setAsyncValue?

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm not sure why 2 children are created/updated when using setValueAsync. Maybe someone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Initially I setup manually under the Employee node some children (Name and Password). Now I'm trying to create a process to be able to update them from an app in java. For some unknown reason 2 sets of children are created/updated(appPassword,name,password,technicianName). even If I delete any of the sets they are added automatically when I do a setValueAsync.

here is my class:

```
package com.mycompany.spring.model;

public class TechShort {
    public boolean active;
    public String name;
    public String password;

public TechShort(boolean active, String name, String password) {
    this.active;
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
}

public boolean getActive() {return this.active;}
public void setActive(boolean active) {this.active = active;} 
public String getTechnicianName() {return this.name;}
public void setTechnicianName(String name) {this.name = name;}     
public String getAppPassword() {return this.password;}
public void setAppPassword(String password) {this.password = password;}     
}
```

and this is how I load firebase database:

```
Map<String, TechShort> techs;
techs = new HashMap<>();
techs.put((String.valueOf(i+1)),
       new  TechShort(Boolean.valueOf(model.getValueAt(i,6).toString()),
                                name1,password1));

 FirebaseDatabase firedb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference db = firedb.getReference().child("Employees");
                    db.setValueAsync(techs);
```

so everything works and the children are created but they are duplicated and I would expect to have just 3 children under the node(
example
active: true
password: 1123223
name: george

instead I have:
active: true
appPassword: 1123223
name: george
password: 1123223
technicianName: george

If i change one of the values(ex. 1123223 to something else both appPassword and password are updated. Hopefully someone can help/guide me to understand how to resolve this.

Comment: Nothing in the code you shared would explain having the values duplicated in the database. So it seems more likely that this happens in the way you invoke the code that you shared.

Comment: I'm loading the map in a loop and adding the elements using put (as in techs.put(...)) and then I update firebase with db.setValueAsync(techs); nothing else that's why it puzzles me. i will try to create the node programatically and then set it with setValueAsync and see how that will go.

Answer (score 0):

as soon as I modified the getters/setters from:

```
public boolean getActive() {return this.active;}
public void setActive(boolean active) {this.active = active;} 
public String getTechnicianName() {return this.name;}
public void setTechnicianName(String name) {this.name = name;}     
public String getAppPassword() {return this.password;}
public void setAppPassword(String password) {this.password = password;}
```

to

```
public boolean getActive() {return this.active;}
public void setActive(boolean active) {this.active = active;} 
public String getName() {return this.name;}
public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}     
public String getPassword() {return this.password;}
public void setPassword(String password) {this.password = password;}
```

the duplication disappeared. it seems that the getters/setters and the variables should match otherwise there will be duplicates.